# a query on compact embedding for critical exponent

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Suppose $(u_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $W^{1,2}(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is abounded domain. Then by the reflexivity there exists a weakly convergent subsequence to it, that converges to, say, $u\in W^{1,2}(\Omega)$. By compact embedding $u_n\rightarrow u$ in $L^r(\Omega)$ for $1\leq r<2^*$. By this norm convergence we can say that there exists a subsequence such that $u_n(x)\rightarrow u(x)$ in $\Omega$. On employing the Egoroff's theorem we obtain $u_n\rightarrow u$ uniformly a.e. excpet on a set of measure arbitrarily small. now can it be said from this uniform convergence that $\int_{\Omega}u_n^{2^*}dx\rightarrow \int_{\Omega}u^{2^*}dx$?. Where am I going wrong?.

Comment: Almost uniform convergence, given by Egoroff, is not enough to conclude the convergence of this integral.

Comment: @Chris Can you elaborate a bit on it?. I am unable to see why the convergence may fail. Sorry if sounds naive.

Comment: you have to show that the integral of $u_n^p$ on this small set is also small

Comment: @Alexander, for instance define $f_n = n^{100}\chi_{[0,1/n]}$. Then $f_n$ converges almost uniformly to zero but $\int f_n$ does not converge to zero. I imagine more of your hypotheses are necessary to exclude this type of behavior.

Comment: Many thanks for the example. I was wondering what allows the convergence to occur with the same argument when $p<2^*$ and fails for $p=2^*$?.